# Search cell for text based on reference table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel column full of text containing comments. I want to summarize these comments in the next column based upon whether the cell contains certain keywords.

Originally I was trying to do this using IF statements, but I soon got an error that I was nesting too many levels. I've now created a table on another cell that's set up as follows:

```
| Keyword      | Output              |  
| send receipt | Needs documentation |  
| etc keyword  | etc output          |
```

How can I now search the cell to see if it contains any of the keywords, and if so, then return the corresponding output? Thanks.

Comment: In which column is the text?

Comment: In which column do you want the output returned?

Comment: In which column are the keywords listed?

Comment: In which column are the possible outputs listed?

Comment: The text and cell I want it to be returned in are on another sheet. Say columns A and B.

Comment: And the keywords and Output are on a separate sheet, say A and B. The sheets can just be Sheet1 and Sheet 2.

Answer (score 0):

One choice is to use an array of your key words.

The following is an array formula so you will need to enter it with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

```
=OR(NOT(ISERROR(FIND(array_of_keywords_to_look_up,cell_to_look_in))))
```

This formula will evaluate to TRUE if the cell you are evaluating has any of the keywords.

And depending on what specific "corresponding output" you are trying to return, you can return  it when true.